# JQuery calculate total price amount it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I'm trying to calculate total price amount of items but it doesn't combine all the item that've been clicked. Its only show a current price of an item. Can you help me? i'm stuck here, thanks!

```
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <% for(var i=0; i<categories.length; i++){ %>
        <div class="tab-pane <% if(i==0){ %> active <% } %>" id="<%= categories[i].id %>a">
            <% for(var j=0; j<items.length; j++){ %>
                    <% if(items[j].category_id == categories[i].id){ %>
                <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="group list-group-image items_img" src="/pic_items/<%= items[j].picture_path %>" data-title='/anime_items/<%= items[j].anime_path %>' data-target='<%= items[j].price %>' alt="Test" />
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                            <%= items[j].title %>   
                            </h4>
                            <p class="group inner list-group-item-text"> <%= items[j].description %> </p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                    <p class="">Width <%= items[j].width %> CM</p>
                                    <p class="">Height <%= items[j].height %> CM</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

and here JQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.items_img').click(function(event){
          var total = $(this).attr('data-target');
          $('data-target:clicked').each(function(){
            total += parseInt($(this).val());

          });
          if (total == 0) {
              $('#cost').val('');
          } else {
            $('#cost').val(total);
          }
        });
   });
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
 var total =0;
        $('.items_img').click(function(event){
   total += parseInt($(this).data('target'));

  });
 if (total == 0) {
  $('#cost').val('');
 } else {
  $('#cost').val(total);
 }
});`

Comment: Can you post a parsed HTML?

Comment: `'data-target:clicked'` what is 'clicked'

Comment: @epascarello clicked mean if I click on each item, it will get data-target. Well I don't know, is it even exist?

Comment: @MaxKasem sounds like you should be using checkboxes, but the image in the label, hide the checkbox.

Comment: `$('data-target:clicked')` - this won't do anything, there's no such tag `<data-target>` - perhaps you meant `$('[data-target]:checked')`

Comment: @Elad Sorry for late reply, what does that mean?

Comment: @MaxKasem The ejs code that you post- is hard to debug and to understand. to understand your problem- i need to sea the final html. so, i asked you to prvide the is as html instead of ejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pesudo `:clicked` does not exist. There is only `:target` but this will only return the latest clicked element.

I could set a class of `is-selected` on click and use that class to access selected elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.items_img').click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        $(this).toggleClass('is-selected');
        $('.items_img.is-selected').each(function() {
            total += $(this).attr('data-target');
        });
        if (total == 0) {
            $('#cost').val('');
        } else {
            $('#cost').val(total);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't know this before thank you but, its still doesn't combine the prices tho.